# Border between card-img-top and card-body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, border, bootstrap-4

I want to have a border between the image and the card-body in a bootstrap card. I have a CSS as follows-

```
.card{
  border-width: 6px;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.card-body{
  border-top-width: 5px;
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 0;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML-

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" alt="Depression" src="images/depression.jpg">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">DEPRESSION</h3>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want-

[image: Card design I want]

What I'm Getting-

[image: Card design I'm Getting]

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: And HTML markup is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border style is mandatory in order to use border. As you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) :

> Note: None of the OTHER CSS border properties described below will
>   have ANY effect unless **the border-style property is set**!

so you may try this code :

```
.card-body{
  border-top-width: 5px;
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-top-style:solid;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Or simply do this :

```
.card-body{
  border-top: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 0;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks! But I wonder why it worked on the 'card' class without border style...

Comment: @GradDev: Shorter version of your code could be as https://jsfiddle.net/jyfcrmty/

Comment: @GradDev if you check Bootstrap CSS you will see that it's already defined ;)